# How to move some folders back after getting directory in java?

Tags: java, path, directory

I used this code and it showed my projects directory.

```
System.out.println("Present Project Directory : "+ System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

for example:  `C:\Users\Yousuf\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Store Management System`

what I want to do is move to C:\Users\Yousuf\Documents only two folders back from the directory obtained through this code. What should I do ?

Comment: I have a Jbutton in my Jframe which takes screenshot of the screen.Now I want to save that image in some folder like Documents or Pictures folder in Windows, and I don't want to use fixed path as it may vary for other PCs.

Comment: Using String.split('\') and reconstruct your path... But It's just a workaround in case you don't have any better solution.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking. How to reconstruct ?

Comment: It depends on where your program runs. On Windows, it likes `"C:" + "\\" + "users"+...`
On Linux or Mac, it likes `"usr" + "/" + ...`

Comment: `Path documents = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir")).getParent().getParent();`. Note this only works with your current configuration. If you launch your app from somewhere else then `user.dir` is different.

Comment: Answered my question using @Arnaud 's comment of possible duplicate

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me I got the parent directory of the parent directory...

```
System.out.println("Present Project Directory : "+ System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    try 
    {
        File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).getCanonicalFile();
        System.out.println("Parent directory : " + file.getParent());
        File file2 = new File(file.getParent()).getCanonicalFile();
        System.out.println("Parent directory : " + file2.getParent());
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the relative path ../../ to navigate 2 folders back. If you add that to the end of a path it's effective location will be 2 folders back.

After that if you want you can use the normalize function to remove redundant elements to give you the actual path 2 folders back. But if you just want to navigate to that folder there's no real need to normalize it.

Just put your path string in the place of `originalPathString`.

```
Path twoFoldersBack= Paths.get(originalPathString, "../../");
```

Or if you want the normalize the path:

```
Path twoFoldersBack= Paths.get(originalPathString, "../../").normalize();
```